# Are there any good Brick Labels out there?

Tags: part-identification, organisation

While resorting my large quantity of LEGO bricks, I was wondering if someone had created a library or file that included labels that could be placed on the outside of containers for a large number of common and not-so-common LEGO bricks. They would just need to contain a picture and the part number of the brick at the least, but one that includes the names would be great too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brick Architect has [labels](http://brickarchitect.com/labels/) available for printing. These are designed to be used with a label maker, but there are also full page PDFs available that can be cut out. Here's an example of how they look:

[image: label example]

Comment: The labels are designed for a label tape of some kind, but there is also a pdf version that can be printed on normal paper. Nice webpage, specialised on building buildings.